# When do we get this error from firestore "A document cannot be written because it exceeds the maximum size allowed."

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Following is the snippet of the code (written in golang) that I tried for checking if the error message `A document cannot be written because it exceeds the maximum size allowed.` comes when I'm inserting too much data in firestore

```
size := 10000000
byteArr := make([]byte, size)
for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
    byteArr[i] = 'a'
}

data := struct {
    BigString  string
    BigString2 string
}{
    BigString:  string(byteArr),
    BigString2: string(byteArr),
}

_, err := firestoreClient.Collection("temp").Doc("5").Create(context.Background(), &data)
if err != nil {
    log.Error("err", err)
    return
}
```

But I get following message when I try this `Request payload size exceeds the limit: 11534336 bytes`.

So, I wanted to understand when do we get `A document cannot be written because it exceeds the maximum size allowed.`

I've already checked for the limitations on the [firestore docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas), it says that limit on firestore doc size is 1MB. so, I tried with 1,000,000 characters in string which should have equalled to 1MB but didn't get any error.

So I've increased the characters to 10x.

Answer (score 4):

You can check the Firestore limitations [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas).

The limit for a document size is  `MiB (1,048,576 bytes)`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Tarik Huber, I've updated my question, I had seen this doc earlier but was not getting the error when doc size was 1MB i.e. 1,000,000.

I missed the `i` in M`i`B part, should have tried with 1,048,576.